# Spotify xdg-open fails, while doing the same open directly works

Tags: 15.04, spotify, xdg-open

When I execute `spotify spotify:track:7u9Vkw4xWtGNjao5uz3fJV`, I can freely listen to the linked track.

But doing `xdg-open spotify:track:7u9Vkw4xWtGNjao5uz3fJV`, I get "Link not found" error in Spotify. How to remedy this?

xdg-open action is `spotify %U`.

Comment: try setting the action to `spotify -uri %U`

Comment: `-uri %U` no longer seems to work, but `--uri=%U` does